# Inserção de elementos em posições específicas de um array

Tags: javascript, array, react, front-end

Boa noite,

Estou tentando criar uma interface de um sistema de salas utilizando **React**, para cada sala podem entrar 8 pessoas. Eu retorno os usuários contidos na sala da API, mas queria tambem indicar os espaços vazio da sala, a minha ideia foi tentar inserir um array default de 8 posições e ao receber os dados da api, apenas inserir a quantidade de dados da api na posições de acordo com a quatidade:

```
const [players, setUsers] = useState(['vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio']);

useEffect(() => {
     api
       .get(`/sala/a092351b-50d6-4f63-a632-4b89417feb7c`)
       .then((response) => setUsers(response.data));
  }, []);
```

Mas dessa maneira eu apenas sobrescrevo, o que preciso retornar é:

[{ user }, { user }, '{ user }', '{ user }', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio', 'vazio']

Existe algum jeito de realizar isso no react? Já estou a um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça hahahahahaha

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

Imagem de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Boas
Você pode usar Array(8), dessa forma é criado um array com 8 posições vazias.

Coloca Array(n) dentro do useState.